# How to pass all requests to some site via specific WAN interface in pfSense?

Tags: freebsd, pfsense

I have multi-WAN configuration on pfSense. I suspect, that some secured web sites (like hosting control panels) dislike that requests are coming from different IPs and hence asking various confirmations from me during work.

How is it good to config pfSense to pass all requests for specific site via specific WAN interface? Or, better, to config it to keep WAN selection for every site for some period of time?

Answer (score 1):

Sticky connections allow you to maintain a single WAN per remote IP, but that's not enough for some sites as they involve communicating with different IPs. I generally recommend not load balancing HTTPS for that reason. In most networks it doesn't use a significant amount of bandwidth, and doing only failover for HTTPS eliminates nearly all the problem scenarios with sessions being bound to a specific IP.